# Is the dynamic initialization of the non-local variable thread-safe

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I have following code in one of the source file of my application:

```cpp
// file1.cpp
#include <memory>

static auto global_variable = std::make_unique<int>(123);

int get_global_variable() { return *global_variable; }
```

Let assume that my application has some threads which call the `get_global_variable`. Is the initialization of the `global_variable` thread-safe?

As far as I know, the `global_variable` is [dynamically initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Dynamic_initialization). I also know that the initialization of static local variables is [thread-safe](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables) since C++11. So, I wonder to know if that exception proves the rule that the other types of variables are not thread-safe initialized or it is also thread-safe and does not produce [data races](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Threads_and_data_races).

I've found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18543786/2235659), but after reading, I'm more confused because the answerer suggested using such pattern:

```cpp
const T& f()
{
    static T t(a,b,c);
    return t;
}
```

which supposedly guarantees the thread-safe initialization.

I also found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1962918/2235659). It states that all globals are initialized before main, so there is only one thread ([Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4706785/peter) rightly pointed out that it is not true - or not every time). However, what if my piece of code is a shared library loaded by `dlopen` function to a program where there is more than one thread?

Comment: is this not answering your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/18543786/4117728 ? What specifically is confusing you?

Comment: Globals at file scope are not guaranteed by the standard to be initialised before `main()`.   They are guaranteed to be initialised before the first usage in the same translation unit (aka source file).   Practically, some implementations will initialise them before `main()`, but that is not required.   The initialisation order of such globals in different translation units is also not guaranteed - and implementations that do initialise them before `main()` mostly don't guarantee a particular order between translation units.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 It is not answering my question, or I can't extract what I need. Just now, I realized that this question is about if the global initialization is single-threaded, but mine is more general: if the initialization of the global is thread-safe.

Comment: @Peter, thanks. I knew that, and I edited my question:). Thanks to pointing it out.

Comment: I think it is just a matter of wording, but now I understand what is confusing you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **[basic.start.dynamic]/4** It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local non-inline variable with static storage duration is sequenced before the first statement of main or is deferred. If it is deferred, it strongly happens before any non-initialization odr-use of any non-inline function or non-inline variable defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized.

I believe this requires the implementation to perform initialization of global variables in a thread-safe manner (if it chooses to defer such initialization).